# How to activate replication slot

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-12, pg-logical

I have 2 logical replication slots in Postgres 12. Suddenly one of them (**100 fields, 16K records**) failed couple of days ago. Obviously, the replication slot is inactive. Then I check a couple of things :

Record count between tables : obviously there is a difference though its only differ by 50 records.

Find out how much behind is the subscriber : 5.13GB

```
SELECT redo_lsn, slot_name,restart_lsn, 
round((redo_lsn-restart_lsn) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2) AS GB_behind 
FROM pg_control_checkpoint(), pg_replication_slots;
```

Chek replication slot using  `select * from pg_replication_slots;`

**slot_name     |plugin  |slot_type**|

--------------+--------+---------+

rep_sub_try2|pgoutput|logical  |

|**datoid|database           |temporary|active|active_pid|xmin|catalog_xmin**|

+------+-------------------+---------+------+----------+----+------------+

| 65977|db_profile_20210714|false    |**false** |          |    |770710854   |

Replication stat using `select * from pg_stat_replication` : nothing here because the slot is disabled

LSN Difference using `SELECT pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), replay_lsn) FROM g_stat_replication`  -- always converge to 0

**pg_wal_lsn_diff**|         **pg_wal_lsn_diff**|

```
---------------+  -->        ---------------+ 

          10004|                           0|
```

Amount of WAL files using `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_ls_dir('pg_wal') WHERE pg_ls_dir ~ '^[0-9A-F]{24}'`;  --4128 (this value has not been changed in 4 days)

Some parameters :

`archive_timeout`  : 3600

`max_wal_size`     : 16GB

`min_wal_size`     : 2GB

`archive_mode`     : ON

`wal_compression`  : ON

`checkpoint_timeout` : 600s

`wal_keep_segments`  : 4000

`max_replication_slots` : 10

`max_wal_senders`    : 5

Questions :

1. I read [here](https://fivetran.com/docs/databases/postgresql/faq/fix-replication-slot-errors) , some reasons for failure are :

- The replication slot didn't return any updates from the Write-Ahead Log (WAL) in the past three
  or more extract cycles.
- The size of the replication slot is in hundreds of GB, approaching 1
  TB.
- The size of the replication slot is often reaching the
  max_wal_sizelimit

How can I prove all those 3 points above ? How can I know the "size of the replication slot" ?

2. Is it safe to just blindly activate the replication by doing some `ALTER` command ? Whats the
   command anyway, I just cant find it.

3, Why the total WAL never changed in the past 4 days ? There are some edits though not so much (around 1 - 10 record per day, not everyday)

Need your very help. I don't want to do something disastrously.
Thank you

Comment: Look in the replicas db log file

Comment: Why not the Publisher, since the replication slot is in there ? @jjanes